# Words squish instead of hidden

Tags: html, css

I have the text "+ Add" in a button. When I squish the button's width, I would like 'Add' to disappear but the  '+' to remain. Normally I would say `overflow: hidden;` but from what I can tell because I have `position: absolute;` that won't work. Ultimately I will probably have to change it to `position: relative;` and mess with the layout, but can anyone tell my why this is?

```
.add_button{
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'EntypoRegular';
    color:white;
    font-size: 34px;
    line-height: 1px;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    box-shadow: rgb(1, 97, 253) 0px 0px 0px 1px inset, rgb(153, 191, 254) 0px 1px 1px 1px inset;
    cursor: pointer;  
    overflow: hidden;
    text-decoration: none solid rgb(255, 255, 255);    
    background: rgb(77, 144, 254) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;
    border: 0px none rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    outline: rgb(255, 255, 255) none 0px;
    margin: 7px 0px;
    width: 15%;
    left: 39%;
}
```

Comment: Are you using JavaScript to change the button size?

Comment: just use jQuery to update the text of the button then. If it's an input button use `.val()` and if it's a `<button>` use `.text()`

Comment: Ok thats good but can you explain why the problem exists to begin with?

Comment: I made [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/bmurn/1/), but I don't believe your button looks the same way. Mine looks... pathetic.